# TextView is taking Theme color of activity as its background instead of its background image

Tags: android, layout

I have created an Activity and applied Theme with Orange colour. I created a custom View object containing a background image and 2 TextView objects. 1 TextView is on Left side and another is on Right side.

I just placed that custom view as Header view on activity. 
Background of TextView must be that background image, but it shows Theme orange color as its background.

My Code:

Header.java:

```
package com.example.themes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Header extends LinearLayout{

    public Header(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        LayoutInflater layInflator = (LayoutInflater)     getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        layInflator.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, this);
    }
}
```

header_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.themes.MainActivity" >

    <com.example.themes.Header
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.themes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do that

1. Use **android:scaleType="fitXY"** or
2. Use **android:background="@drawable/image"** instead of **android:src**
3. And the best is to remove that ImageView and apply **android:background="@drawable/image"** on the RelativeLayout

Comment: I'd say never use fitXY as scale type. Better yet centerCrop. With fitXY you may have really awkwardly looking images.

Comment: @Mike I agree but for plain background images it should not be a problem.

Comment: @anish - Also remember that when you apply a theme on an activity all the views of the activity use that property by default.

Comment: In case the size and ratio fits the size of the View container which'll host the image, yes. But generally speaking, using fitXY is not a good idea. Better have your image a little bit cropped and displayed properly, than have it stretched.

Comment: So, add android:background="@null" in TextView to remove theme from its background.